# загрузка картинки на сервер php

Tags: php, javascript

здравстувйте, есть ajax форма, и в ней инпут для картинки:

```
<input id="postimage" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="load_preview(this, 'post');" name="postimage" style="display: none;">
```

затем изображение передается в формате base64 и сохраняется с помощью file_put_contents.

но что делать если при загрузке gif изображений происходит ошибка 413 Request Entity Too Large

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если **nginx**(/etc/nginx/nginx.conf)

```
client_max_body_size 200M;
```

Если **apache**(/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf)

```
LimitRequestBody 1073741824
```

Также можно и в **.htaccess** прописать

```
LimitRequestBody 1073741824
```

Answer (score 0):

NGinx (2GB) `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 2gb
}
```

Apache (2GB) `.htaccess` || `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` || `/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
LimitRequestBody 2147483647
```

И фильтруй `image/svg` || `image/svg+xml` ибо там может быть XSS